# Weird behaviour when using nested table-cell

Tags: html, wordpress, css, tablecell

I have created a horizontal menu, and I am having trouble when one of the cell have a larger content than others.

To see what happens, I edited 2 JSFiddle in order you observe the issue :

[**JSFiddle with equal content**](https://jsfiddle.net/akysrs3t/1/)

[**JSFiddle with one of the cell larger than others**](https://jsfiddle.net/akysrs3t/2/)

I used `ul` in `display : table`, `li` in `display : table-cell` and a link tag inside li in `display : table-cell`.

I don't get why the nested table-cell that represent the link tag behaves adding a weird space in top when the inner content is bigger than other cells.

Can someone point me in the right direction ? Feel free to completly changes the css if needed, the only requirement is to keep the tag hierarchy as I use Wordpres `wp_menu_nav()` function that gives me this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Chrome bug, which violates the [CSS tables spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout):

> **`vertical-align: baseline`**: The baseline of the cell is put at
>   the same height as the baseline of the first of the rows it spans
>
> The baseline of a cell is the baseline of the first in-flow [line
>   box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box) in the cell, or the first in-flow table-row in the cell,
>   whichever comes first. If there is no such line box or table-row, the
>   baseline is the bottom of content edge of the cell box.

The `li` elements are `table-cell`s with the default `vertical-align: baseline`. They contain an `a` `table-cell`, which is wrapped inside anonymous `table-row` and `table`. So the first lines of the `a` should be aligned, but it seems Chrome seems to align the last lines.

You can fix it with

```css
#menu > li {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
#menu > li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 80px;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  border: solid 1px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#menu > li > a {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 80px;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  background: lightgrey;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="">first link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Second link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Third link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Fourth link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Fifth link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Sixth link Sixth link Sixth link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the resolve.
https://jsfiddle.net/akysrs3t/7/

```
body {
  margin : 0px;
}

#menu {
  list-style-type : none;
  margin : 0px;
  padding : 0px;
  display : table;
  width : 100%;
  table-layout: fixed; /* makes the with distribute equally amongst the items of the menu */
}

#menu > li {
  display : table-cell;
  border : solid 1px black;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  vertical-align : middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu > li > a {
  display : block;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background : lightgrey;
}
```

You can see the results in the example over JSFiddle.
Have a look at the values for table-layout: as well.

You do not really need the calc().

Bests,
George